# Retain array in memory on application restart

Tags: c++, qt, memory

I have a C++ backend server application. When our users login to the application, a SESSION Object (Complex C++ Object containing database connections, access rights, pointers etc) is created for each user. The Object is then maintained in an array. I am using a batch script to restart application in case of crash.

The issue is, in case the application crashes, the array of SESSIONS is destroyed. When the application starts again the array is empty. Hence the users are required to login again.

Is there a any method to retain the array of SESSIONS across application restarts?

I am using Qt 5.5 framework and the OS is Ubuntu Linux.

Code:

```
static QHash<QString,Session*> sessions

class Session {
bool logged_in;
QString aID;
QString sID;
QMap<QString,QMap>;
QMap<QString,QVariant> m_vars;
bool m_database;
int m_minutes;
QTimer* m_sessionTimer;
bool m_valid;
CustomClass* CustomClass;
CustomClass2* CustomClass;
QTimer* timer;
QList <CustomClass3*> objects;
}

CustomClass {
//15 getter-setter functions...
CustomClassInterface interface; //PIMPL
}

CustomClassInterface {
DatabaseClass database;
CustomUserClass userClass;
//...More 5-6 QList items
}

CustomClass2 {
    //15 getter-setter functions...
    CustomClass2Interface interface; //PIMPL
    }

    CustomClass2Interface {
    DatabaseClass database;
    CustomUserClass userClass;
    //...More 5-6 QList items
    }

...
The class is huge so I can't write the whole code here
```

Adding serialisation to all class would require to rewrite bunch of libraries. So, isn't there any other approach without implementing serialisation. Like mmap or something.

Comment: I think you want to serialize the object when it's created

Comment: Can you post the structure of your session class

Comment: A possible (better) approach would be to maintain the logged in status in a DB table

Comment: I don't believe so. It's essential that the OS cleans up resources like memory after exit of process. An exception might be shared memory/a memory mapped file. Isn't it an option to write/load a file with resp. data?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Separation of concerns
You can use a separate process to handle/store the credentials.

Comment: That may point to the right approach, but for an answer, consider that you don't even write one single complete sentence...

Comment: Or just fix the crashes ;)

Comment: What if that process is also crashed?

Comment: SESSION object contains lots of data of the user such as user specific database connections, pointers, data etc which can't be communicated using IPC I think

Answer (score 2):

Can you save the sessions in a database/file when you create/update them? Whenever you start the server, restore them.

Comment: this is the best possible approach since the application seems to have a connection with DB already...and maybe re-build the SESSION objects again at the startup

Comment: Cannot do that, as the SESSION object is complex object containing pointers and few of them doesn't support serialization.

Comment: @Antony Well then you'll have to add serialization support to them, since you need to serialize them. Worst case, more fundamental changes will be necessary.